# Unit Test for ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking

Lets assume I have a method like this

```
public void scheduleCleanup(String parameter) {
    final SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject(parameter);
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    executor.schedule((Runnable) () -> cleanupService.startCleanup(someObject),
                CLEANUP_TIMEOUT_SEC, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

which means that `cleanupService.startCleanup(someObject)` is invoked after `CLEANUP_TIMEOUT_SEC` which is actually coming from some properties file.

For me it is very clear that I can create `SomeObject` and write the unit test for `cleanupService.startCleanup(someObject)`, but what do I do with `scheduleCleanup` method?

1. I assume that I need to mock it, but how do you do it in this case?
2. Is it possible to avoid mocking and what is the best way in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to avoid using/calling the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor in your unit tests. I would replace ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with a ScheduledExecutorService and have it injected into the class:

```
@Inject ExecutorService executor;

public void scheduleCleanup(String parameter) {
   final SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject(parameter);
   executor.schedule((Runnable) () -> cleanupService.startCleanup(someObject),
            CLEANUP_TIMEOUT_SEC, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Then you can simply verify that `executor.schedule(Runnable, long, TimeUnit)` was called at the appropriate places.

Comment: This is useful for unit testing the `scheduleCleanup` method but, unless i'm reading it wrong, that's not what the question is asking

Comment: @blgt So what is it asking?

Comment: Testing `cleanupService.startCleanup`, whatever that is. Perhaps OP could clarify

Comment: @forty-two, thank you for your answer. This is quite interesting idea and could be quite beneficial, however, in this case we need to change the production code and as we know we should not change it to achieve the testing needs.

Comment: @blgt, I am asking how to test scheduleCleanup method. I mentioned that it is very clear for me how to write the test for startCleanup. The point is that we have some method (example startCleanup) and it is invoked after some time by scheduleCleanup, but scheduleCleanup can be also called several times.

Comment: My bad, I didn't get that from the question. This is the correct answer then